# How to send email as reminder automatically

Tags: python, django

I am trying to figure out how I can send email notification for due task automatically.

I have due date for a task and I want it to send it at that specified date but 1 hour before it is due.

I'have got to creating custom command

notify.py

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Email notification'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        Job.generate_emails()
```

models.py

```
@classmethod
    def generate_emails(cls):
        pass
```

That is what I'have done so far.

Comment: Use celery. http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: I would suggest https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple tasks I prefer to make a small [custom admin command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/) and add a cron job on the server.

If the task is not as much repeative, you can add an additional command that will run frequently and will clear a small task queue such as to check if an email is to be sent.

Alternatively there are packages such as [Celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#) as @ruddra already kindly pointed out (Celery did not support Python 3.4 last time I checked).